# Metadata URL for Yammer

Tags: api, yammer, office365-restapi

I am working on Yammer REST APIs

I was wondering if there is any metadata URL to get the schema for Yammer objects like messages, users, suggestions etc.

Let me know if there is any way to get the metadata information in Yammer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no metadata API available. The only resource is the documentation at https://developer.yammer.com

Oh, and the questions and answers here on stackoverflow.